# How to do nested highlighting of part of a row in an array?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, tikz-styles, arrays, highlighting

I'm trying to highlight part of a row in an array, where some parts are "double" highlighted so it appears darker.

From a previous question, I tried the following:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{%
  highlight/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,fill=blue!15,draw,fill opacity=0.5,
inner sep=0pt}
}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)] 
    \node (#1) {#2};}
%
\newcommand{\Highlight}[1][submatrix]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \node[highlight,fit=(left.north west) (right.south east)] (#1) {};}
}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{ *{5}{c} }
a &0 &0 &0 &0 \\
b & c &0 &0 &0   \\
d & e &f &0 &0  \\
\tikzmark{left}{\tikzmark{left}{\tikzmark{left}{\tikzmark{right}{$g$}}\Highlight[first]}} & \tikzmark{right}{$h$}     \Highlight[second]&\tikzmark{right}{$i$}  \Highlight[third]&j&0  \\
k & l & m & n &o 
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

The goal here is to have g highlighted 3 times, h highlighted 2 times, and i highlighted 1 time, with all the highlights overlapping  and carrying across columns. What I end up with is an array that looks like this:

[image]

Obviously this has lots of issues, including a large gap before the last row and that the highlights don't center around the values. Also, if it is easier to use a matrix or something similar, it doesn't need to be an array.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution will not quite work because the nodes with the same names will overwrite each other.  Also your construction looks very complicated.  This is a little easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{%
  highlight/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    fill=blue!15,
    draw,fill opacity=0.5,
    inner sep=0pt,
  }
}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]\node (#1) {#2};%
}
%
\newcommand{\Highlight}[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[highlight,fit=#1] {};%
}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{ *{5}{c} }
  a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  b & c & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  d & e & f & 0 & 0 \\
  \tikzmark{left}{$g$} & \tikzmark{first}{$h$} & \tikzmark{second}{$i$} & j & 0 \\
  k & l & m & n & o \\
\end{array}
\Highlight{(left)}
\Highlight{(left)(first)}
\Highlight{(left)(second)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or much better, use a TikZ matrix and put the highlight in the background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,matrix}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  highlight/.style={
    rounded corners,
    fill=blue!15,
    fill opacity=0.5,
  }]
  \matrix[matrix of math nodes,execute at begin cell=\mathstrut] (m)
  {
    a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    b & c & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    d & e & f & 0 & 0 \\
    g & h & i & j & 0 \\
    k & l & m & n & o \\
  };
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \filldraw[highlight] (m-4-1.north west) rectangle (m-4-1.south east);
    \filldraw[highlight] (m-4-1.north west) rectangle (m-4-2.south east);
    \filldraw[highlight] (m-4-1.north west) rectangle (m-4-3.south east);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know how to change the highlighting so the black border around it is gone?

Comment: Add draw=none to the highlight style.